# Script to back-up all files in my current folder

Tags: bash, shell

I created a Linux shell script for backup, in setting up a variable for include which files for backup, can i assign the files needed in one variable like below?

```
SRC_DIR=/etc/{passwd,shadow,group,gshadow,my.cnf,dovecot.conf}
tar -cvf $DESDIR/$FILENAME -g $SNF $SRC_DIR
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this, assuming file names don't contain spaces or newlines, is to create a variable with the file names:

```
FILES=$(echo /etc/{passwd,shadow,group,gshadow,my.cnf,dovecot.conf})
tar -cvf $DESDIR/$FILENAME -g $SNF $FILES
```

This assumes a shell supporting *brace expansion* (not all do).

Comment: @kenleung I was too hasty, that was only for extracting and listing the TOC.

Comment: if put `/etc/{passwd,shadow,group,gshadow,my.cnf,dovecot.conf}` to file, `tar -cvf -T file $DESDIR/$FILENAME -g $SNF` is ok. I want one bash script do for it.